# Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How can i update my user profile using serializer, I got this error when i update my user profile: Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `accounts.serializers.AccountProfileSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.

```
class AccountProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.gender')
    phone = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.phone')
    location = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.location')
    birth_date = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.birth_date')
    biodata = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.biodata')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'last_login', 'date_joined',
                  'gender', 'phone', 'location', 'birth_date', 'biodata')



class AccountProfileViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        profile = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        serializer = AccountProfileSerializer(profile, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request):
        profile = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        serializer = AccountProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: can you please copy paste the full traceback of error?

Comment: AssertionError at /api/accounts/profile/
The `.update()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `accounts.serializers.AccountProfileSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.


This is the full Error

Comment: short answer inside `create` method pop data which belongs to `accountprofile` and separate them from fields which does not belong to `User` model and then save both of them separately inside `create`. Or you can edit the question and add `accountprofile` Model there, so I can help you with full implementation.

Comment: sorry I meant `update` method

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by override update method in serializer

```
class AccountProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.gender')
    phone = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.phone')
    location = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.location')
    birth_date = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.birth_date')
    biodata = serializers.CharField(source='accountprofile.biodata')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender',
                  'phone', 'location', 'birth_date', 'biodata')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('accountprofile')
        profile = instance.accountprofile

        # * User Info
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get(
            'first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get(
            'last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get(
            'email', instance.email)
        instance.save()

        # * AccountProfile Info
        profile.gender = profile_data.get(
            'gender', profile.gender)
        profile.phone = profile_data.get(
            'phone', profile.phone)
        profile.location = profile_data.get(
            'location', profile.location)
        profile.birth_date = profile_data.get(
            'birth_date', profile.birth_date)
        profile.biodata = profile_data.get(
            'biodata', profile.biodata)
        profile.save()

        return instance
```

Comment: We just need to check that "accountprofile" is there when one of those fields are not passed