# Extended user class properties not updating

Tags: python, django

Would like to allow users to update their profile, getting the error

`Field name 'city' is not valid for model 'User'.`

For context, I extended my default user class in models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/%Y/%m/%d', default='media/placeholder.png', blank=False, null=False)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

When a user updates a profile I use this endpoint in urls.py:

```
path('update_profile/<int:pk>', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

Here is my UpdateProfileView:

```
class UpdateProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer
    def profile(request):
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                serializer_user = UpdateUserSerializer(user, many=True)
                if serializer_user.is_valid():
                    serializer_user.save()
                    return Response(serializer_user)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(data='no such user!', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my serializers.py:

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name','city','country']
        extra_kwargs = {'username': {'required': False},
                        'email': {'required': False},
                        'password': {'required': False},
                        'first_name': {'required': False},
                        'last_name': {'required': False},
                        'city': {'required': False},
                        'country': {'required': False}}


        def validate_email(self, value):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(email=value).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"email": "This email is already in use."})
            return value

        def validate_username(self, value):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(username=value).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"username": "This username is already in use."})
            return value

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            #re-writing updated profile info from request
            user = self.context['request'].user

            if user.pk != instance.pk:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"authorize": "You don't have permission for this user."})

            instance.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
            instance.last_name = validated_data['last_name']
            instance.email = validated_data['email']
            instance.username = validated_data['username']
            instance.profile.city = validated_data['city']
            instance.profile.country = validated_data['country']
            instance.profile.bio = validated_data['bio']

            instance.save()

            return instance
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2):

In this part of the serializer:

```
fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name','city','country']
```

'city' is not an attribute of User, it's an attribute of Profile. In order for DRF to update it, it needs to know how to access it.

Example:

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)
    city = serializers.CharField(source='profile.city')
    [...]
```

Comment: This is giving me the error `The '.update()' method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit '.update()' method for serializer 'signup.serializers.UpdateUserSerializer', or set 'read_only=True' on dotted-source `

Comment: You have defined an update method - just not in the right place. Your update() is part of your Meta inner class. You should move it outside the class Meta, but still inside the serializer.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847000/write-an-explicit-update-method-for-serializer

Comment: Thanks, now getting the error  ` "authorize": "You don't have permission for this user."
`. Not sure why because I could update first_name and last_name without any issues

Answer (score 0):

like @Nick ODell said

"**'city' is not an attribute of User, it's an attribute of Profile. In order for DRF to update it, it needs to know how to access it.**"

but couldn't we just change the model the serializer class is using like

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name','city','country']
        extra_kwargs = {'username': {'required': False},
                        'email': {'required': False},
                        'password': {'required': False},
                        'first_name': {'required': False},
                        'last_name': {'required': False},
                        'city': {'required': False},
                        'country': {'required': False}}
```

Comment: does this answer your question? If not, this is the incorrect place to post this.

Comment: Getting the error message `Field name 'username' is not valid for model 'Profile'`.
`

Comment: Ok looking at the code again that makes sense your profile has a user instance and doesn't extend the user class itself.